# HTML Expandable Nav Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple'ish issue, i trying to create an expandable drown.. using jQuery toggle.

I can get the overall feature working, but for some reason my sub menu is over lapping the main.. I believe is has something to do with the attribute **padding-top:70px**;

I am trying to re-create the NAV menu found here: http://adidasdesignstudios.com/

**HTML:**

```
<header class="menu">
<div class="sub">
    <nav>
        <ul class="sub-options">
            <li>
                <div>
                    <a href="#all_crafted">1_</a>
                    <section><br>Check out product designs.</section>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <a href="#all_about">2_</a>
                    <section><br>Find out more about.</section>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <a href="#all_in">3_</a>
                    <section><br>Learn design.</section>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <a href="#all_jobs">4_</a>
                    <section><br>View current job opportunities.</section>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <a href="#all_cities">5_</a>
                    <section><br>See our locations.</section>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <a href="#all_academy">6_</a>
                    <section><br>Learn more.</section>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu {

color:#515151;
height:70px;
left:0;
width:100%;
background-color:rgba(19,19,19,0.8);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CC131313,endColorstr=#CC131313);
top:0;
position:fixed;
zoom:1;
margin:0 auto;
display:block;
padding-top:70px;


.sub {
background:#fff;
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
width:100%;
border-radius:3px;
/*box-shadow:0 2px 4px #ddd;*/
border:1px solid #ddd;
display:none;
/*padding:40px 0 3px;*/
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".menu").hover(
    function(){$(".sub").slideToggle(400);},
    function(){$(".sub").hide();}
);
```

I think im close, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You do not have an initial menu item like "adidas" in you example?

Comment: @veelen - Thanks, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: You have to provide an element that is parent of the menu to hide/show, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/z5gZh/

Comment: I dont think my question is being read correctly. My issue is not with displaying/toggling the sub menu.. Its with the sub menu overlapping the main.. See fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/8vxd9/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd fix it with css alone (nno jQuery): Example => [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vxd9/4)

Also, you are missing an '}' in your code:

```
.menu {
        color:#515151;
        height:70px;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        background-color:rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.8);
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CC131313, endColorstr=#CC131313);
        top:0;
        position:fixed;
        zoom:1;
        margin:0 auto;
        display:block;
        padding-top:70px;
    **}**
    .sub {
        background:#fff;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:2;
        width:100%;
        border-radius:3px;
        /*box-shadow:0 2px 4px #ddd;*/
        border:1px solid #ddd;
        display:none;
        /*padding:40px 0 3px;*/
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/8vxd9/3/ Although its nearly there, the end result doesn't look like the menu is expanding, but simply over lapping.

Comment: Additionally, how would i go about displaying the menu item horizontally. I have tried ul, li {
    display:inline
}

Comment: And .sub-options ul, li {
    display:inline;
}

Comment: thanks for your fiddle - there is no javascript in your example, is that correct???

Comment: Thats correct, like its done on the adidas site. I made it in Chrome, so if you are using another browser, you might need to use another vendor prefixes for the transition.

Comment: Thanks - seems to work in FF and IE9.. I may have to test other browsers.. Any ideas how i can block the submenu items in the center, like on the site?

Comment: If this works, you could mark my answer as the solution to your query. I don't know what you mean by "block the items in the center", and I think that's also a new question to be posted.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the perfect answer, but this works when I tried it:

```
.menu {
    color:#515151;
    height:70px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.8);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#CC131313, endColorstr=#CC131313);
    top:0;
    position:fixed;
    zoom:1;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
}
.sub {
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:3px;
    /*box-shadow:0 2px 4px #ddd;*/
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    display:none;
    /*padding:40px 0 3px;*/
    top: 70px;
}
```

I just deleted the 'paddign-top: 70px' from .menu and added a 'top: 70px' to .sub

Answer (score 0):

In your class `.sub`, you set its position to `position:absolute` but nowhere you specify a position.

Try to add `top:100%;` in your class `.sub`. This way, it will be right under your menu. So no more overlapping.